# Taskbar has bluish flicker when Pi boots up in 1080p

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I am having some problems getting the Pi running at a 1080p res on my new TV (HDMI of course).
First of all whenever I edit the config.txt file through my kali laptop, the next time I open it in my laptop (after the memory card has been inserted and the Pi has booted once), the config.txt file becomes entirely blank. I just have these four lines in my config.txt file-
config_hdmi_boost=7
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16

I got the last two values by running the tvservice command. Anyways, with **ONLY** these lines in my config.txt I can boot up to 1080p resolution but my taskbar and windows have a strange bluish flicker.

With **ONLY** the line config_hdmi_boost=7 I am able to boot up to a 1360*768 resolution without any problems.
Here is a snapshot:- 
[image]

Currently I am using my Pi with **ONLY** the config_hdmi_boost=7 line, which is booting up to 1360*786 perfectly fine.

Comment: Try setting "HDMI_SAFE=1" in your config.txt file with nothing else in the file. from your pc, then save and reboot your Pi, and post an image of what happens afterwards. Here is a par for reference: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

Comment: @MohammadAli I've tried that already, the Pi boots up in 640*480 resolution

Comment: But does the blue problem go away?

Comment: Yes it does, the blue problem only surfaces when I try running the Pi in 1080p using the above config

Comment: Have you tried using different HDMI monitors? Have you gotten better results?

Comment: @MohammadAli I tried earlier with a tv and it worked fine...

Comment: Try hdmi_pixel_encoding=1 then try hdmi_pixel_encoding=2 and hdmi_pixel_encoding=3 and hdmi_pixel_encoding=4 one at a time and please tell us what happens when you make each change(note some may not provide any output)

Comment: @MohammadAli you want **ONLY**  these lines to be in the config.txt or do I add them alongside my current config?

Comment: Alongside should be fine

Comment: @MohammadAli Okay I'll post back the results asap

Comment: Ok, photos would be helpful, if you could also indicate the model of tv that you are using and its age that would be great

Comment: The TV is just a few days old, its Samsung, model number is G-23 or something

Comment: How's the testing going?

Comment: how did/is the testing going?